# API On R: Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : Timeout was reached

Tags: r, api, curl

I tried to call the [Darksky API](https://darksky.net/dev/) for weather data, after giving the API key and run the request, i got the error as below:

> ```
> Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
>   Timeout was reached
> ```

Did anyone had a similar issue when calling API on R?